# Read The Registry Using Win 8 App?

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

I'm trying to see if it's possible to read the registry from a Windows 8 app. I can usually use Registry.GetValue() but I don't have that option when creating the Win 8 app. Doing some digging shows that the Registry.GetValue() belongs to the Microsoft.Win32 namespace which isn't available in the Win 8 app references properties tab.

I did some googling but I couldn't find any concrete evidence that you cannot read the registry. I fear that I won't be able to do this because of sandboxing Win 8 apps.

Comment: You are correct. In Windows 8 Store apps (Modern / Metro), they are sand boxed to prevent access to system-level items like the Registry. If you need to have an application access the registry, it needs to be a non-Windows Store project type.

Comment: That's what I feared. I'm looking into App Container (their version of sandboxing) but I can't find anything that flat out states Store apps cannot access the registry.

Comment: It's not possible to flat out state everything an app cannot do since that is an infinite set. Unrestricted registry access would violate application isolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to, you can do that by using interop services.

So import the WinAPI functions you need (you can get the signatures from [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/regopenkeyex.html)):

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(UIntPtr hKey, string lpSubKey,
      uint ulOptions, int samDesired, out UIntPtr phkResult);
```

And make your own wrapper around them.

**But as far as I know, that's not allowed and your app won't pass the certification.**

Comment: Thanks for this info. I was able to find my answer then in their certification requirements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx.